# How to render a flexdashboard to PDF without "Row" and "Column" headers

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I have a flexdashboard R markdown file which nicely renders the required dashboard. I am also producing a PDF version of the dashboard for some users who require print-outs and I want to make sure I can do this from the same script by calling the render function with multiple output types. This works fine, except for that fact that the "Row" and/or "Column" markers, which are required to make sure that the dashboard is correctly structured, are printed as titles in the resulting PDF. Here is an example:

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: pdflatex
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

Row {data-height=400}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Stuff in Row 1

Row {data-height=400}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Stuff in Row 2
```

The PDF output of this looks as follows:

> **Row**
>   Stuff in Row 1
>   **Row**
>   Stuff in Row 2

What I would like is the PDF output to not have the "Row" headers:

> Stuff in Row 1
>   Stuff in Row 2

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

it's a hack and results in a empty line in pdf. i just comment the markers.

```
<!-- Row --> {data-height=400}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```