# Is it possible to create an RMarkdown document in landscape mode?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am creating a flexdashboard document that looks like this (dashboard style basically). However, our end-users will not be interacting and drilling down to this like one would in a traditional dashboard. Instead, we are going to send these out as PDFs to our audience. I know you can create parameterized reports in a traditonal PDF or HTML RMarkdown report, however I am looking to create that document in a landscape mode/dashboard style view.

[image]

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424368/how-to-render-a-flexdashboard-to-pdf-without-row-and-column-headers) is someone with a very similar issue, wanting to *print* the dashboard to pdf for sharing, still no answer either.

Comment: Wow, thank you. This is just what I was looking for